# How to use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage in Android/IOS

Tags: android, python, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I use `freeze_graph` to export my model to a file named `"frozen.pb"`. But Found that the accuracy of predictions on `frozen.pb` is very bad.

I know the problem maybe `MovingAverage` not included in `frozen.pb`.

When I use `model.ckpt` files to restore model for evaluating, if I call `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.999)` , then the accuracy is good as expected, else the accuracy is bad.

**So How To export a binary model which performance is the same as the one restored from checkpoint files?**  I want to use `".pb"` files in Android Devices.

[The official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/moving_averages) doesn't mention this.

Thanks!!

Freeze Command:

```
~/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
  --input_graph=./graph.pbtxt \
  --input_checkpoint=./model.ckpt-100000 \
  --output_graph=frozen.pb \
  --output_node_names=output  \
  --restore_op_name=save/restore_all \
  --clear_devices
```

Evaluate Code:

```
... ...
logits = carc19.inference(images)
top_k = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k=10)

# Precision: 97%
# Restore the moving average version of the learned variables for eval.
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(carc19.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
for k in variables_to_restore.keys():
  print (k,variables_to_restore[k])
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

# Precision: 84%
#saver = tf.train.Saver()

#model_path = '/tmp/carc19_train/model.ckpt-9801'
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, model_path)
... ...
```

Comment: Same issue at github [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9724](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9724)